# Change tooltip of clicked element in ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

After click of element I'm executing function and on its success I want to chagne tooltip of clicked element.

I have more than one element with this tooltip displayed in ngRepeat loop. However I want to change tooltip only on currentTarget element (element which was clicked). Currently I'm displaying tooltip as interpolated string from controller and after function success I'm changing this string. **It cause that every element with this tooltip have new tooltip not only the one which was clicked.**

```
<div ng-repeat="n in auctions">
    <img src="img/heart_icon.png"
         alt="Dodaj do wishlisty"
         class="category__record-button--wishlist-icon"
         data-ng-if="$parent.authentication.isAuth"
         data-ng-click="addFollowAuction(n.id)"
         uib-tooltip="{{ categoryConfig.followInfo }}"
         tooltip-placement="top"
         tooltip-trigger="'mouseenter'"
         tooltip-append-to-body="true">
</div>
```

So `categoryConfig.followInfo` is this string I was writing above and it is changed after `addFollowAuction()` function succeed:

```
$scope.addFollowAuction = function (auctionId) {
    console.log(auctionId);
    auctionsFollowService.addFollowAuction(auctionId)
        .then(function (response) {
            if(response.detail === 'success follow') {
                $scope.categoryConfig.followInfo = 'Pomyślnie dodano ten przedmiot do wishlisty!';
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.log('err adding to wishlist ' + err);
        });
};
```

And then all images displayed from loop have new tooltip info but I want only attached new info to clicked image. I tried to use `$event` but it didn't work since I was changing `$scope.categoryConfig.followInfo` either way.

How to attach new tooltip info only to clicked element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need followInfo to be an array of items and each item has its own tooltip reference:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in auctions">
<img src="img/heart_icon.png"
     alt="Dodaj do wishlisty"
     class="category__record-button--wishlist-icon"
     data-ng-if="$parent.authentication.isAuth"
     data-ng-click="addFollowAuction(n.id)"
     uib-tooltip="{{ categoryConfig.followInfo[n.id] }}"
     tooltip-placement="top"
     tooltip-trigger="'mouseenter'"
     tooltip-append-to-body="true">
```

notice `uib-tooltip="{{ categoryConfig.followInfo[n.id] }}"`

```
$scope.addFollowAuction = function (auctionId) {
console.log(auctionId);
auctionsFollowService.addFollowAuction(auctionId)
    .then(function (response) {
        if(response.detail === 'success follow') {
            $scope.categoryConfig.followInfo[auctionId] = 'Pomyślnie dodano ten przedmiot do wishlisty!';
        }
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('err adding to wishlist ' + err);
    });
};
```

notice `$scope.categoryConfig.followInfo[auctionId]`
don't forget to init followiInfo before: `$scope.categoryConfig.followInfo =[]`